# ¿Como obtener el texto plano de una cadena HTML de forma segura?

Tags: javascript, html, seguridad

Necesito obtener el texto que se encuentra dentro de una cadena `HTML` la cual puede contener código malicioso, por lo cual necesito que el método no ejecute `scripts`, descargue recursos externos, etc.

#### Ejemplo de `HTML`:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css" style="display:none;"> P {margin-top: 0;margin-bottom: 0;}</style>
<script>alert('Cuidado script!')</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body dir="ltr">
  <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
    Buenos días Señor X.</div>
  <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
    Muchas gracias por el envió.</div>
  <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
    Cordialmente</div>
  <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
    Sr Y&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="DAB4FAD8-2DD7-40BB-A1B8-4E2AA1F9FDF2"><br>
    <table style="border-top: 1px solid #D3D4DE;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 55px; padding-top: 18px;">
            <a href="https://www.avast.com/sig-email?utm_medium=email&amp;utm_source=link&amp;utm_campaign=sig-email&amp;utm_content=webmail" target="_blank"><img onload="alert('Cuidado imagen!')" onerror="alert('Cuidado error!')" alt="" width="46" height="29" style="width: 46px; height: 29px;" src="https://ipmcdn.avast.com/images/icons/icon-envelope-tick-round-orange-animated-no-repeat-v1.gif"></a>
          </td>
          <td style="width: 470px; padding-top: 17px; color: #41424e; font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;">
            Libre de virus. <a href="https://www.avast.com/sig-email?utm_medium=email&amp;utm_source=link&amp;utm_campaign=sig-email&amp;utm_content=webmail" target="_blank" style="color: #4453ea;">
www.avast.com</a> </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <a href="#DAB4FAD8-2DD7-40BB-A1B8-4E2AA1F9FDF2" width="1" height="1"></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Resultado esperado:

- No se debe ejecutar ningún `script`
- No se deben descargar recurso externo (*imágenes, estilos, etc*)
- El resultado debe ser el texto:

  ```
   Buenos días Señor X. Muchas gracias por el envió. Cordialmente Sr Y Libre de virus. www.avast.com
  ```

Comment: Cualquier otra solución es mas que bienvenida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una solución es usar [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function getHtmlText(html) {
  let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html'),
    text = doc.body.textContent || '';
  // Limpiamos los espacios
  text = text.trim().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')
  return text;
}

//
let html = document.getElementById('html').value;
console.log(getHtmlText(html));
```

```html
<textarea id="html">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css"> P {margin-top: 0;margin-bottom: 0;}</style>
<script>alert('Cuidado script!')</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body dir="ltr">
  <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
    Buenos días Señor X.</div>
  <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
    Muchas gracias por el envió.</div>
  <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
    Cordialmente</div>
  <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
    Sr Y&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="DAB4FAD8-2DD7-40BB-A1B8-4E2AA1F9FDF2"><br>
    <table style="border-top: 1px solid #D3D4DE;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 55px; padding-top: 18px;">
            <a href="https://www.avast.com/sig-email?utm_medium=email&amp;utm_source=link&amp;utm_campaign=sig-email&amp;utm_content=webmail" target="_blank"><img onload="alert('Cuidado imagen!')" onerror="alert('Cuidado error!')" alt="" width="46" height="29" style="width: 46px; height: 29px;" src="https://ipmcdn.avast.com/images/icons/icon-envelope-tick-round-orange-animated-no-repeat-v1.gif"></a>
          </td>
          <td style="width: 470px; padding-top: 17px; color: #41424e; font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;">
            Libre de virus. <a href="https://www.avast.com/sig-email?utm_medium=email&amp;utm_source=link&amp;utm_campaign=sig-email&amp;utm_content=webmail" target="_blank" style="color: #4453ea;">
www.avast.com</a> </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <a href="#DAB4FAD8-2DD7-40BB-A1B8-4E2AA1F9FDF2" width="1" height="1"></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
</textarea>
```

---

### Créditos:

- [Respuesta original SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47140708/3791844)

Answer (score 2):

Escapar todo posible script malicioso es bastante complicado. Aquí están muchas de las vulnerabilidades XSS:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet pero no son todas porque se van agregando.

El script malicioso puede no necesariamente ser JavaScript, porque podría ejecutarse en el lenguaje del servidor.

Lo ideal es no hacer esto, pero en caso de hacerlo hay que tener en cuenta cada posibilidad, aquí dejo el artículo de OWASP referente a la prevención de ataques XSS https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: @Marcos si, cómo dije en el anterior comentario es la representación de lo que sucede si termina de nuevo en un navegador.

Comment: No es una vulnerabilidad de DOMparser en si, es que DOMparser está hecho para otra cosa. Está hecho para parsear. Usado de esta forma es vulnerable.

Comment: @Marcos quité el ejemplo del DOMparser porque se presta a confusión. En mí caso yo no usaría DOMparser porque no puedo saber dónde termina ese código que ingreso a mí sistema. Pero depende lo que se haga puede parecer una exageración.

Comment: Si bien es cierto lo que planteas en tu respuesta, esta aún no responde la pregunta. ¿Como harías para obtener el texto y de forma segura? Lo que suceda después con ese texto, es otro tema.